# How to get SUM from sum of relational field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models Sell and Slip where:

```
class Slip extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $dates = ['bill_date'];


    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sell::class);
    }
}
class Sell extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    function slip()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Slip');
    }

}
```

in migration I have column for slips table:

```
Schema::create('slips', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('customer_name');
            $table->string('customer_age');
            $table->string('customer_gender');
            $table->dateTime('bill_date')->nullable();
            $table->integer('paid')->nullable();
            $table->integer('discount')->nullable();
            $table->integer('doctor_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and for sell:

```
Schema::create('sells', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('product_id');
            $table->integer('sell_price');
            $table->integer('doctor_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('slip_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have this query:

```
$slips = Slip::with(['doctor']);
        $slips = $slips->withCount(['orders as total_sales' => function ($q) {
            $q->select(DB::raw('SUM(sell_price)'));
        }]);
$slips = $slips->whereBetween('bill_date', [$from, $to])->whereHas('doctor', function ($q) {
                $q->where('id', request()->query('doctor'));
            });
```

What I want is to get is the sum of all sell_price from the database after I filter. I can get sum of sell_price(total_sales) for each slip, but I want sum of total_sales before I do pagination.

I know a way I to do that:

```
$slips->get()->sum('total_sales')
```

But if I do this with 10,000 data, it takes 5 min to load which I don't want that. I would like to get the sum from the database. Is there any workaround to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `withSum()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-counting-and-custom-select-statements

```
$slips = Slip::withSum('orders', 'sell_price')
    ->get();
```

And you can get each sum of `sell_price` by

```
foreach($slips as $slip) {
    $slip->orders_sum_sell_price;
}
```